# How to get an NFT Project's image (ie: OpenSea profile picture)

Tags: nft

I'm trying to find a way to enter an NFT project's contract address and get an associated project profile image (ie: image that shows up on OpenSea, rarity.tools, etc. at the top of a collection's page) - I don't see it in the contract metadata but I might be looking in the wrong place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there. Is there a particular project contract you were looking at? (Might be easier for the answer-er to use it as an example.)

Comment: Yep, RumbleKongLeague (contract 0xef0182dc0574cd5874494a120750fd222fdb909a)

https://opensea.io/collection/rumble-kong-league

Answer (score 1):

For the example you've given in the comments...

- Open the token contract in Etherscan (i.e. [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xef0182dc0574cd5874494a120750fd222fdb909a))
- Open the Contract tab, then ReadContract
- In the `tokenURI` dropdown, insert the ID of the token you're interested in
- The query will return the IPFS path to a JSON file
- One of the fields in the JSON file will give a path to the image

For example, for Kong #7620, the associated returned JSON path is `ipfs://QmUD7G9xD3beung6RDGV5ZaXEMjaSCDBhe9TjYWqw9jmnV/7620`. (You can view this using an IPFS public gateway at https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUD7G9xD3beung6RDGV5ZaXEMjaSCDBhe9TjYWqw9jmnV/7620).

The image path can then be seen to be https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcZx3PksH4HMwCzjbCuvvrRBH7crgnN7dSbyDs6bdScUk

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not talking about about an individual NFT, rather the project as a whole, like the "RKL" logo that's on the OpenSea page

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x18rNFBg9leLL9TtHkhhiC8cwIurh1UhMKU6TL_JMbGyUsY8MTMhyPiz8Nz7VRJHShEgIQlCP070UB9gGWvJ05ST7IclovIWnwAUww=s130